# Assigning a signature to a module

Tags: module, ocaml

I'm reading the [Tezos whitepaper](https://tezos.com/whitepaper.pdf), which uses   Ocaml and I am having trouble understanding the syntax.  I only know basic ocaml and am not too familiar with modules.

```
module Context = sig
type t
type key = string list
val get: t -> key -> Bytes.t option Lwt.t
val set: t -> key -> Bytes.t -> t Lwt.t
val del: t -> key -> t Lwt.t
(*...*)
end
```

It uses `module Context` instead of `module type Context`, what does this mean? Is it just a typo or does it have a different meaning. I have only found examples of assigning modules using `struct`.

Comment: In general, don't trust any code is correct unless it compiles (and, in the case of dynamic typing of course, runs) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an error to me. As you say, `sig ... end` is a module type. So it can't be a module, which is a value of such a type. If I enter your code I get a syntax error on the token `sig`, which is what I would expect.

Most likely `type` was left out: `modulel type Context = sig ... end`.